# XNA Game Class Q: When is the default(?) ContentManager instance 'Content' initialized?

Tags: c#, xna

As far as I understand, *Program.cs* is the entry point for an XNA program since it incorporates the *Main* method.

In the *Main* method, a Game1 (child of Game) instance is declared and initialized.

The constructor for *Game1.cs* class does not involve any *ContentManager* initialization but the object *Content* can be called in the constructor. That means somewhere between *Main* method and *Game1* constructor, *Content* object is initialized but I can't for the life of me find any documentation where and how this is taking place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally the constructor for a your game would look somethng like this ...

```
public Game1() : base()
{
    ...
}
```

So one of two things is happening ...

1. this variable is initialised in the base ctor a this runs before yours.
   the variable Content is a class level variable declared in the manner below in the base type

It seems like pretty basic C# to me ...

```
class Game
{
    public ContentManager Content = new ContentManager();
    ...
}
```

There are also some wierd bits in .Net where they do stuff like ...

```
ContentManager content;

public ContentManager Content 
{
   get 
   { 
       if(content == null)
          InitialiseContentManager();

       return content;
   }
}
```

Comment: pretty much right on. Except there is no null check in the getter. here is the reflected code right out of the XNA framework: http://pastebin.com/kGugaBbq